# Forge Model Derivative API POST job fails

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

**The scenario:**

1. Upload a Revit file to a bucket using the Data Management API.
2. Request a conversion to SVF job using Model Derivative API *POST Job*
3. Poll for status using Model Derivative API *GET Manifest*

This works *most* of the times, but occasionally the SVF job fails at some arbitrary point, that is: The manifest status is "failed" and the progress is xx%.

When requesting the job again for the same file it fails in the same way, but with a different progress value. I have seen values in the range from 26% to 99% for the same file. Likewise, the time elapsed varies from few minutes to hours.

This happens most often for "larger" rvt files (~200+ mb).

I have downloaded the file from the bucket and thus checked that it has not been corrupted. In other words, it seems that this is a problem internally in Forge.

**The question** is of cause: Why does the jobs fail? And how can I prevent it?

Comment: Hi Henrik~ Could you do me a favor add `x-ads-force: true` to your HTTP request header while calling the `Model Derivative API POST Job` and test it again? You can see more description in here (https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/).

Comment: If your data or descriptions could not be post here publicly, please repeat your question again and send it via the 'forge.help@autodesk.com'. 'Please Remove sensitive data or information before you send it to me', thanks.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to 'x-ads-force: true' - I had forgot about that. But I can't say if that solves the actual problem. As I mentioned this is not a consistent problem. If it shows again I may contact you directly and point you to the actual file.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I will gladly help you if this issue takes place again. At that moment, please contact me via the `forge.help@autodesk.com`. Thank you.